# Set permission to user and folder - laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, apache, permissions, internal-server-error

Today with GIT I update my app but after that I got Internal Server Error.

I try to solve problem with command:

```
sudo chown -R ireserve:ireserve /home/ireserve/public_html
```

and

```
chgrp ireserve -R /home/ireserve/public_html
```

but again the same error:

here is my folder permissions:

[image]

Any idea what is a problem and how to solve?

I also try this commands:

```
find public_html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
find public_html/ -type d -exec chmod ug+s {} \; 
find public_html/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; 
chown -R ireserve:ireserve public_html
chown -R ireserve:ireserve public_html
chmod -R 777 public_html/storage
chmod -R 777 public_html/bootstrap/cache/
```

Comment: can i see the apache log?

Comment: Wed Jun 20 22:50:04.876882 2018] [:error] [pid 32460:tid 1400342219136] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx:41982] SoftException in Application.cpp:657: Directory "/home/ireserve/public_html/public" is writeable by group